# Properly including math.js library in a .js file

Tags: javascript, include, nan, math.js

I want to use the math.js library in my javascript file - say it's called webpage.js.
What I did so far is having a script tag in the main html file that calls math.js, and then another that calls webpage.js. The script tags are as follows:

```
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.2.5/math.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-fWwwg2Pf3Ox5xhm9xCE7O+czkI2dSkqN6gUZumzGrx0="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/lat-long.js"></script>
```

Is that it? Can I now go to my webpage.js file and use "Math.whatever" without having to 'import' or 'include' anything at the beginning of the file?

The reason I am asking this is because I have the following code which is not working properly (anything using Math.something is returning a NaN, which I assumed was because Math.js was not imported properly).
Here is the code for reference:

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
    console.log("dLat------------------" + dLat);
    var a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) *
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
            Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    console.log("d is " + d);
    return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}
var distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
    locationLatUser,
    locationLongUser,
    supplier.latLng.latitude,
    supplier.latLng.longitude
);

//all the values used in the function call exist and are defined.
console.log("distance between user and supplier: " + distance);
```

Console logging any value in the above code gives me a NaN.

Comment: Why can't you just use webpack to bundle all your javascript code and include single JS file in your `index.html`?

Comment: `Math` is the built in mathematics module in javascript. `math` (notice the small `m`) is the library you're using. So either you stop including a library for basic mathematical operations. Or you have to change all occurrences of `Math` to `math`.

Comment: Probably you are getting `NaN` because of the parameters you are sending to `getDistanceFromLatLonInKm`. Could you `console.log` them please.

Comment: I copied your code without change anything, it works! As @Olian04 said Math is built in library in JS, you don't need to import external lib for this

Comment: Olian04 - Thank you that clarifies it a bit. But I still have a question: do you mean that sin and cos are basic mathematical operations? (and don't need the inclusion of the math.js library?). If not then I guess I have to change Math to math. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ghadir yes, in this context I am referring to `sin` & `cos` as basic mathematical operations.

Comment: Pedro they are console logged and all are being printed (so they exist and are defined as I said in original question). That what confused me. Ahmet well that confuses me more as to why I am getting a NaN error. Thank you (all of you) for trying to help anyway

Comment: Since you're getting `NaN`, you're probably passing something else than a number to one of your `Math.*` calls. Maybe one of your arguments is a string by accident? Try logging `typeof lat1` for example.

Comment: For anyone still interested in what happened here, it looks like the problem is that the variables in the function call are large doubles, and the math functions are not handling them properly. (ex: supplier latitude 33.8766711 - supplier longitude 35.5038173). I used normal (4, 55, 77, 6) numbers in the function call and got a normal result. So now I am off to round my original numbers. Thank you all again!

Comment: Olian you are right. I logged typeof my variables, two were numbers, the other two were undefined. So I now know what the problem is. Thank for being a helpful human being.